# In Python, how can I detect if a website is down?

Tags: python, http, request

In other words, if it returns 200, print True. Else, False.

How can I detect that?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to get people to write code for you. You're expected to try and figure it out yourself and ask for help if you get stuck. That said, you can use the standard `urllib2` library, or the better, nonstandard `requests` library, to try and access a web site and see what response code you get.

Comment: @Russell Borogove: Citation needed

Comment: @username: It's on meta.

Comment: Not a good question, but there are some good answers so...

Comment: @pst: With over 1000 questions, you'd expect him to know better...

Comment: @pst: How on earth did this go unclosed after six whole months? Good grief. I was just alerted to this via a flag. I thought the community would have helped six months back, but it looks like they've failed us this time. There, closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library to access the website:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://example.com')
>>> r.status_code
200
```

If the `status_code` is not 200 or if you get an exception, it's not functioning properly. You can read about the relevant exceptions (such as `requests.exceptions.Timeout`) [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts) and [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions).

Comment: +1 for requests. You can also use `r.ok` to see if the request returned an "OK" result, that is, a 200- or 300-range code.

Comment: Requests is a fine library, but the standard library is perfectly capable of solving the OP's problem without any of the difficulties that Requests is meant to address.

Answer (score 4):

You can use function [urllib2.urlopen](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) like that:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> print urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com").getcode()
200
```